# Relocate image on mouseover

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to recreate a mac style menu bar is c# on visual studio 2012. I can get the image to move on mouseEnter and relocate back to the original place on mouseLeave. I do this by setting the location of the picturebox.

The problem I have is when I mouseEnter the image if I leave the mouse in the area at the bottom of the image between the bottom of the old image location and the bottom of the new image location the image will jump constantly between the two location.

Can anyone advise how to stop this or avoid it.

```
private void pic1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pic1.Location = new Point(328, 300);
}

private void pic1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pic1.Location = new Point(328, 316);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do this in WinsForms

Comment: Some kind of feedback (comment/upvote/mark correct answer) is always appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True, since moving the image triggers the `MouseLeave` event, Leave callback sends it to its original location, thus triggering `MouseEnter` and so on for ever and ever (unless you move the mouse away).

I would suggest you eliminate MouseLeave callback and keep a state of where the image is:

```
private bool retracted = false;
private void pic1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (retracted)
    {
        pic1.Location = new Point(328, 316);
    }
    else
    {
        pic1.Location = new Point(328, 300);
    }
    retracted = !retracted;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to detach event handler before moving image location, then attach it back after. Something like this :

```
private void pic1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pic1.MouseEnter -= pic1_MouseEnter;
    pic1.MouseLeave -= pic1_MouseLeave;

    pic1.Location = new Point(328, 300);

    pic1.MouseEnter += pic1_MouseEnter;
    pic1.MouseLeave += pic1_MouseLeave;
}
```

Comment: Cheers but the jumping effect still remains.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the solutions but none had the desired effect but I have come up with a solution using mouseHover and mouseLeave. On hover moves the image to the desired location ad the leave returns it to the original spot.

```
    private void pic1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pic1.Location = new Point(328, 316);
    }

    private void pic1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pic1.Location = new Point(328, 310);
    }
```